# How to add a binding to UIElement's property, without SetBinding() method?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I'm asking about Column object - DataGridControl from Xceed's WPF Extended Toolkit. I need to create a Column in code, and add a binding to its Width property. Column class doesn't expose the SetBinding() method. Although in XAML - it supports bindings as usual:

```
<xcdg:Column Width="{Binding Path=ColWidth}">
```

Is there a way to make such binding to some ViewModel's property? Or a walkaround, possibly, to apply some Style or Template (static? created in code?) that would have a binding?

Comment: `SetBinding` is a convenience method for some other static method of the same name if i remember correctly. Forgot where it's defined. EDIT: Thanks, google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding(v=vs.110).aspx), it's the method that should be used internally by [`FrameworkElement.SetBinding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598270(v=vs.110).aspx).